# LESS add a whitespace on nth-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, whitespace

### I currently have this lees code:

```
.myclass{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    & li{
        display: none;
        &:nth-child(1),:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3){
            display:inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

And as you can see what i want is that only show me the first three `li` elements, the rest will be displayed as `none`. But the compile make this **Output:**

```
.myclass{
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
}
.myclass li{
    display: none;
}
.myclass li:nth-child(1),
.myclass li :nth-child(2),
.myclass li :nth-child(3) {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can see there is a whitespace in `:nth-child(2)` and `:nth-child(3)` so **only the first child is working right.**

How can i delete this whitespace?

Comment: You should put `&` before every selector in the list (as `&` applies only to the selector it appears in, not "all subsequent" selectors). In simple words, should be: `&:nth-child(1), &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(3)` (these are three distinct selectors).

Comment: Feel free to add an answer, to choose it as the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're only using [LESS's immediate parent selector (`&`)](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) on the first `:nth-child` declaration and not on the other two. It becomes obvious to see that if we put a line break between each of the declarations:

```css
&:nth-child(1),
:nth-child(2),
:nth-child(3){
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To fix this, you simply need to place that `&` before the other two `:nth-child` declarations:

```css
&:nth-child(1),
&:nth-child(2),
&:nth-child(3){
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

Furthermore, you don't need the `&` before the `li` selector:

```css
.myclass {
    li {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this you can make a repetitive structure

```
.myclass{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  & li{
      display: none;
      /* In range() pass as an argument the number of iterations you need to perform */
      each(range(3), {
        /* And to the argument of nth-child() you pass the value (the current iteration number) */
        &:nth-child(@{value}) {
          display:inline-block;
        } 
      }) 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.myclass {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
.myclass li {
  display: none;
}
.myclass li:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
}
.myclass li:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
.myclass li:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

For more information I recommend the documentation: https://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each